# How to change hostname to set static Ip address?

Tags: plone

I use plone 4.3.4. I want to know where should I change the hostname of a plone site. I want to access my Plone site globally using the IP address, without providing the 8080 port.

Comment: The hostname of a Plone site is not something related to Plone or other CMS at all. Look at your front-end server configuration. How are you accessing your Plone site right now?

Comment: @@keul: I m accesing my plone site using localhost:8080

Comment: @@keul: what i want to do is to access my plone site in another machine.So that I want to use my ipaddress in plone during bin/instance

Comment: Try connecting to your plone instance using your system ip address like `192.168.1.105:8080`

Comment: @@Loqman: how can connect? I dont get you

Comment: I suggest you to use a web server that run on port 80 in front of Plone: See http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/front-end/apache.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020332/plone-with-apache-proxy...

Comment: @@keul: plone site is in fedora server.  can you please tell me how to change it?

Comment: @@Keul: Thanks for your reply:). I didnt get the work done yet. but i really thankful for all replies.

Comment: @Plonedoubts you could add an HTTP frontend on your server (Apache or nginx) that listens at port 80 and proxies that to 8080 (where plone is waiting for connections)

Comment: Isn't it about changing the client's port, merely? If so, set the `http-address`-option to 80 in the instance-part of your buildout.cfg

Answer (score 0):

What Ida said.

Alternately you can edit the zope.conf file and change http-address to 80.

You may have to run the instance as sudo (for accessing port 80).