# Add a simple html and css page in Plone

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Having a Plone 4 website what is the easiest way to add a new section that will contain a simple html + css page without any other styles or content?

I received the html content and css for this section and I'm trying to find the easiest way to have it working. My idea is to use diazo rule in this case, something like: replace body with that html + css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a folder "Section" (any title you want here)

In folder Section add a folder CSS and a folder Images. Add a file for each file used by your html page.

Go to section/manage_main and add a Page Template.
Important: the Id must be index_html

Edit index_html, copy your html content here, fix the links to use the images from section/images and css from section/css

(Based on bullet 4 here: http://docs.plone.org/4/en/old-reference-manuals/archetypes/zope_to_browser.html)

Answer (score 1):

A better option: serve your static content using a front-end web server (Apache or NGINX).

Having this layer in front of Zope is always a good idea, and you really don't need an application server for static contents.

See also [Plone with Apache Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020332/plone-with-apache-proxy)